# Swagger UI is not loading after adding @PathVariable Resource to Controller

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I have Spring Boot and Swagger Integration in my application. I have added one more resource in my existing controller after that, swagger ui stops loading

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` page is not loading and giving `HTTP ERROR 406` Error

One more thing if I remove @PathVariable from below API then swagger-ui is loading successfully.

Added below resource in existing controller

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get Employee Information")
@GetMapping("/{employeeId}")
public EmployeeResponse employeeInfo(
    @PathVariable("employeeId") String employeeId,
    @RequestHeader(value = "x-client-id", required = false) String xclientId){
    return service.getEmployeeInfo();
}
```

Below library versions I am using -

```
classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE'    
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1'
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1'
```

When I try to load swagger-ui.html, getting

```
Client : [UnknownClient] - An exception was thrown by a controller Could not find  
acceptable representation:
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find  acceptable 
representation
```

I think newly added resource path is conflicting with `swagger-ui.html` root path. I cannot change the resource path and also swagger ui path as api contract is already decided .

Comment: Have you tried using the most recent versions, say. `2.9.2`

Comment: I did not tried that version. Does that version has the fix for this?

Comment: Its the version I use with no issues

Comment: Hi @mcgowan.b, I tried updating `springfox-swagger-*` version to `2.9.2` but no luck, I am getting same error.